# Is there a way to grab a range of indices in a numpy array using a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to be able to do something like this `arr[..., 3:8]`, but I'd like to be able to use a tuple returned from some other function. Let's say it's `tup=(3,8)`. No I know that `arr[..., tup]` would just return the 3rd and 8th indices of the last dimension of `arr`. Is there a native way to do what I want though?

Oh, and I'm not looking for the answer: `arr[..., tup[0]:tup[1]]`. If you know for sure there's no better way, please feel free to put that as an answer.

Comment: [`slice(*tup)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've actually never used slice! But I don't think it's a numpy array method

Comment: No, it's not a method at all, it's a built-in function. But `slice(3, 8)` creates the same thing `3:8` does when indexing.

Comment: oh wow. been using Python for a looong time and didn't know this. `arr[..., slice(1,4)]` feel free to drop that in an answer